# CakePHP Complex Relationship

Tags: cakephp

I have the following tables:

```
teams(id, name)
team_users(id, team_id, user_id) 
users (id, username)
projects (id, project_name, team_id)
```

A team hasMany users, Users hasMany teams, a project belongsTo a team.

If I call $this->User->find(); It returns the information of the user and the team's he belongs to.

What I want to do is, I would like to get a count of the projects he is associated with. Meaning:

John Doe is a member of Team X and Y. X has 2 projects and Y has 3 projects. I would like to return number of projects as 5, some sort of virtual field. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

If you had properly set up you model relationship this query is all you need:

```
$this->User->virtualFields = array('total_projects' => 'COUNT(*)');
$user_projects = $this->User->find('all',array('fields' => array('total_projects', '*')));

//$user_projects["User"]["total_projects"] -> this will result to 5 base on your question above or you can debug this by: debug($user_projects) so you can see the content of the array
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the "counterCache" option in the relation.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#belongsto

```
class Project extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Team' => array(
            'className' => 'Team',
            'foreignKey' => 'team_id',
            'counterCache' => true
        )
    );
}
```

You'll need to add a new field `project_count` to your `teams` table, CakePHP will do the rest.